# How To View Database Diagram?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, sql-server-2012

I am working on a project which requires me to write several `POCO classes` using `Entity Framework Code First`. There is a lot of  entity relationships and inheritance going on and its hard to keep track of everything just looking at the code. Now, as we know, `Entity Framework Code First` yields an `.mdf` file as your database, and i was thinking for verification, a database diagram would server me better.

Is it possible for me to view my database diagram in this scenario, and how may i do so??

Answer (score 0):

You could always point it to a SQL Server Express database - by default an MVC 4 project uses LocalDB but if you're more comfortable in management studio you can always create your own database and change the connection string to that.

Also from memory I believe you can also attach an mdf file in management studio but may have trouble while the application is running. But I could be thinking of something else there.

Comment: I have no intention of going back to `SQL Server Express` after working with `LocalDB`. i was also looking for `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`, i don't think they have this version out yet, version 2008 does not connect to `LocalDB` which i have on my local machine

Comment: I found Management studio 2012 at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062